# What is the difference between test and include in Webpack 2?

Tags: webpack-2

The docs say:

```
{ test: Condition }: The Condition must match. The convention is to provide a RegExp or array of RegExps here, but it's not enforced.

{ include: Condition }: The Condition must match. The convention is to provide a string or array of strings here, but it's not enforced.
```

1. Is the difference really only that one takes a string or array and the other takes a regex or array?
   and
2. Does include work the same as Webpack 1?

Answer (score 1):

After more research I think I can answer my own question:

1. In the webpack 1 documentation test is used for file names and include is used typically for directories
2. Looks like it but issuer doesn't seem to exist in Webpack 1